# Aggregate to insert array values in a document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have the following collection

```
{
    "Id" : "12345-7",
    },
    "Stock" : [ 
            {
                "Code" : "1",
                "Qty" : 5.0
            }, 
            {
                "Code" : "3",
                "Qty" : 7.0
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
    "Id" : "22222-0",
    "Stock" : [ 
            {
                "Code" : "3",
                "Qty" : 10.0
            }, 
            {
                "Code" : "10",
                "Qty" : 2.0
            }
         ]
    }
```

And I have this list:

```
{1 , 10}
```

My expected output is:

```
Id : 12345-7
Code: 1
Availability : in stock


Id : 12345-7
Code: 10
Availability : out of stock

Id : 12345-7
Code: 1
Availability : out of stock


Id : 12345-7
Code: 10
Availability : out of stock
```

Basically, if the values of the list doesn't exists in the `Stock.Code` I need to generate a document with the value of the list. The last document of the expected output is `out of stock` because there is a rule that is `in stock` if `Qty >= 3`

I've tried this

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
{
  "$unwind" : "$Stock"
},
{
  "$match" : 
  {
       "$in" : ["Stock.Code", list]
  }
},
{
       "$projoect" :
       {
             "Id" : "$Id",
             "Code" : "$Stock.Code",
             "Availability" :
             {
                "$cond"
                        ...
             }
       }
}
])
```

My doubts are:

- Can I do this using only one aggregate?
- What is the best way to do this? I'm using pyMongo to code that, is better to do this in database side or code side
- How Can I change my aggregate `Code` and `Condition` to match my expected output?

Comment: are you sure this is not a mistake? Id : 12345-7 Code: 10 Availability : in stock, 12345-7  doesn't have Code 10 at all

Comment: @Takis_ It was a typo, I've edited the answer and now is correct! Thanks

Comment: the bellow answer worked for you? this was what you need?

Comment: I'll test now, as soon as i finish i ll post here, just a moment

Comment: I have 2kk registers in my collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- add the list(Code) in each document
- unwind Code
- filter each array for the `Code` to exist in array and with qty>=3
- if filter result is empty the `Code` is `out of stock`
- else `it is in stock`

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49da)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"Code": ["1", "10"]}},
 {"$unwind": {"path": "$Code"}},
 {"$set": 
   {"Availability": 
     {"$cond": 
       [{"$eq": 
         [{"$filter": 
            {"input": "$Stock",
             "cond": 
               {"$and": 
                 [{"$gte": ["$$this.Qty", 3]},
                  {"$eq": ["$$this.Code", "$Code"]}]}}},
           []]},
       "out of stock","in stock"]}}},
  {"$project": {"_id": 0, "Id": 1, "Code": 1, "Availability": 1}}])
```

---

**Edit1 (array operators)**

If you want try this also that tries to keep things local, and unwinds only when done.

Query

- from stock keep the codes that are also in the code-list
- out-stock codes = the missing codes (as documents)
- in-stock codes = the found codes (as documents)
- concat in stock, without stock, project
- unwind and replace root with those subdocuments

*the main difference is that works local in each document,
and unwinds only when done, maybe will be faster

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49db)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"codes": ["1", "10"]}},
  {"$set": 
    {"Stock": 
      {"$reduce": 
        {"input": "$Stock",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": 
          {"$cond": 
            [{"$and": 
                [{"$gte": ["$$this.Qty", 3]},
                  {"$in": ["$$this.Code", "$codes"]}]},
              {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", ["$$this.Code"]]}, "$$value"]}}}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"out-stock": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": {"$setDifference": ["$codes", "$Stock"]},
          "in": 
          {"Id": "$Id", "Code": "$$this", "Availability": "out of stock"}}}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"in-stock": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$Stock",
          "in": 
          {"Id": "$Id", "Code": "$$this", "Availability": "in stock"}}}}},
  {"$project": 
    {"stock-info": {"$concatArrays": ["$out-stock", "$in-stock"]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$stock-info"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$stock-info"}}])
```

---

**Edit2(array operators and keep qty)**

If you want to keep the quantity also you can try this.
Its a bit different maybe its faster than both but i cant test it.

If code exists on an Id it will have the quantity it had, else it will have quantity 0 (you can put any valua if code was not found, or even remove the field completely) change this part `"Qty": 0`

Query

- map Stock, the codes that are in code-list, becomes documents with
  `Availability` in or out on stoke, the other values map to null
- find the missing-codes= codes that are not in Stock like the first doesn't even have the code 10, and make the documents with out-of-stock and qty=0
- concat found codes in Stock and missing codes
- unwind and replace root

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49e0)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"codes": ["1", "10"]}},
  {"$set": 
    {"Stock": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$Stock",
          "in": 
          {"$switch": 
            {"branches": 
              [{"case": 
                  {"$and": 
                    [{"$gte": ["$$this.Qty", 3]},
                      {"$in": ["$$this.Code", "$codes"]}]},
                  "then": 
                  {"$mergeObjects": 
                    ["$$this", {"Availability": "in stock", "Id": "$Id"}]}},
                {"case": {"$in": ["$$this.Code", "$codes"]},
                  "then": 
                  {"$mergeObjects": 
                    ["$$this", {"Availability": "out of stock", "Id": "$Id"}]}}],
              "default": null}}}}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"Stock": 
      {"$filter": {"input": "$Stock", "cond": {"$ne": ["$$this", null]}}},
      "missing-codes": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": {"$setDifference": ["$codes", "$Stock.Code"]},
          "in": 
          {"Availability": "out of stock",
            "Id": "$Id",
            "Code": "$$this",
            "Qty": 0}}}}},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id": 0, "Stock": {"$concatArrays": ["$Stock", "$missing-codes"]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$Stock"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$Stock"}}])
```

Comment: I'm running your answer on my collection with 2kk documents.

Comment: It Worked, 3 minutes with spark! Thank you so much!

Comment: i tried one more query, if you see this maybe try it and send some feedback, on which one was faster.

Comment: is it possible to set the `Stock.Qty` at output too?

Comment: i added one more query, to save the Qty also and you see it in results, i think this is what you mean by set, if you want to change the Qty you can do that also, but i think you meant just keep the Qty they had.

Comment: On line 96 of the last query... this line is to set Qty equals 0 if `stock.Qty < 3`? I'm asking because is showing Qty= 2 . Is it possible to when the value of the stock is less than 3 set it to 0 insted of stock Qty?

Comment: I've edited your answer to set values to 0 when out of stock

Comment: ok good if now it is what you need, at 2 million with unwind you said it took 3 min, with the  last query? if you measure time, send if you can, just curious